# For loop in R with key value

Tags: r, loops

What is the equivalent way in R to

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
}
```

that means

```
arr<-c(a=1,b=2,c=3)
key<-names(arr)
val<-arr
for(i in 1:length(arr)){
 print(paste(key[i],val[i]))
}
```

Comment: The only difference I see is that your output is formatted differently, which is easily amended by using string arguments in `paste()`. If that is not it, the question seems not entirely clear.

Comment: I don't understand. The code you have supplied will also generate the key value pair? So what's missing?

Comment: @Dr.Mike: I think he is looking for a more elegant way to write this loop.

Comment: @f3lix thx for your understanding, Iam already learn R. My expirence by writing code are that I think often in languages like PHP and Java and if I would need a lapply I see now differnces to do it in for loop, I know loops are bad things in vector languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the [foreach](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/) you can write:

```
foreach(key=names(arr), val=arr) %do% print(paste(key,val))
```

---

And you can define your own `forkeyval` function:

```
forkeyval = function(arr, .combine=function(...){NULL}, ...) {
                foreach(key=names(arr), val=arr, .combine=.combine, ...) }
```

Which lets you write:

```
forkeyval(arr) %do% print(paste(key,val)
```

Comment: Though I like the *foreach* package, I think my [kv](https://github.com/decisionpatterns/kv) package provides a more syntactically natural solution to the OP question.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming `var` is a list of key value pairs, a more generic foreach loop can be achieved with the following snippet:

```
for(key in names(var)){
  value<-var[key]
  print(paste(key,'=',value))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

R likes to vectorize things. You can do:

```
sprintf("Key: %s; Value: %s", names(arr), arr)
# [1] "Key: a; Value: 1" "Key: b; Value: 2" "Key: c; Value: 3"
```

Or for a nicer output, pass it through `cat`:

```
cat(sprintf("Key: %s; Value: %s", names(arr), arr), sep = "\n")
# Key: a; Value: 1
# Key: b; Value: 2
# Key: c; Value: 3
```

Comment: I know about that it would better to think in vectors, but the calculation is more complex, mybe you can give a better solution for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571595/passed-through-a-xml-tree-and-replace-objects) and I will decide if I could use this priciple for the solution what I am doing now.

Comment: What you link to is a completely different problem. For what you asked here, I provided what I and most people will consider the right answer. When you start mastering R, maybe you will realize it is not "more complex" but quite the opposite: fewer keys strokes, fewer function calls, and it will run faster.

Comment: Look at the link in a more general way it is quite the same under point 2).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `kv()` from the [**kv**](https://github.com/decisionpatterns/kv) package. It is exceedingly light weight and departs very little from base R syntax.

```
for( . in kv(arr) ) {
  cat( "Key:", .$k, "Value:", .$v, "<br />\n" ) 
}
```

**Disclosure:** I wrote **kv**.