# Replace values in vector a index vector

Tags: r, replace

The folowing example shows the replacing of certain elments in a vector. The elments which should be replaced are given by key and the new value is given by val. Which approach you suggest to do so in r?

```
 set.seed(1)
 x<-sample(1:10,20,T)
 key<-1:10
 val<-sample(1:3,10,T)
 y<-numeric(length(x))
 for(i in 1:length(key))
   y[x==key[i]]<-val[i]
```

Comment: Haven't you asked [**a few**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18898463/1478381) variations [**of this**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18845987/1478381) question [**before?!**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18572921/1478381). I think you should study the answers to your previous questions. Especially [**this one I gave you**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18898800/1478381). It contains the answer!

Comment: This will also not work quite as expected because you are changing the elements of `x` then comparing to `key` again in a recursive manner. e.g. the 10th element after the loop is 2, it should be 3.

Comment: @SimonO101, I edit the start post and I could not see how to use match in this case?

Comment: And did you compare `y` to my answer below?! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try and use `match` like this....

```
x <- val[ match( x , key ) ]
```

Here is an example showing how they are the same...

```
#  This awkward loop...
set.seed(1)
 x<-sample(1:10,20,T)
 key<-1:10
 val<-sample(1:3,10,T)
 y<-numeric(length(x))
 for(i in 1:length(key))
   y[x==key[i]]<-val[i]

#  Gives the same result as...
x <- val[ match( x , key ) ]

#  Which can be verified by...
[1] TRUE
all( x == y )

#  But you should not be surprised that...
identical( x , y )
[1] FALSE

#  Because....
typeof(x)
[1] "integer"
typeof(y)
[1] "double"
```